# Show / hide divs clarification with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

A highly similar question has been asked already, and it has partly solved my problem, but I'd like to know if `class` or `id` NAMES can be used in this example instead of `ul li` - `.menu`, `#menu`, etc.

css: `div { display:none; background:red; width:200px; height:200px; }`

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            var i = $(this).index();
            $('div').hide();
            $('div:eq('+i+')').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Hj7/

Apologies in advance if this question is stupid, but I've been mucking about with it for a while and cant figure it out.

Comment: could you explain your question about `class` and `id`?

Comment: the example uses list item elements where I'd prefer to use a class or id - I only want the js to apply to certain divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu .list').click(function(e) {
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('div').hide();
        $('div:eq('+i+')').show();
    });
});
```

There is no need at all for using a loop.

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/S6Uqx/)

Answer (score 0):

To improve your js, you can use the arguments of the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function(i, e) {
        $(e).click(function() {
            $('div').hide();
            $('div:eq('+i+')').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why would `$.each` improve it?

Comment: @Northernlights: what i pointed out was the use of `$.each` because you already have an index and don't have to use `var i = $(this).index();`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this snippet some time ago to hide anything with an id. 
The elements img, div, a, li ul, table etc: all need to have style set to visible/relative
*visibility: visible; position: relative;*

The function changes visible to hidden to hide the element then sets the position to absolute to keep the element from creating a white space in its position.

Fiddled http://jsfiddle.net/ShawnsSpace/URRDy/

```
<div id="togglethis" style="visibility: visible; position: relative; border: 4px dotted;">Click the button to toggle this Div</div>
```

---

```
<button onclick="toggle('togglethis');">Toggle</button>
```

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function toggle(obj) {
    var item = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (item.style.visibility=='visible') {
        item.style.visibility = 'hidden';    
     }
    else {
        item.style.visibility = 'visible';
     }
     //
    if (item.style.position=='relative') {
    item.style.position = 'absolute'; 
    }
    else { 
    item.style.position = 'relative'; 
    }   
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: you should look at the style.display property and the difference in it's behavior from the style.visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question about using the ID and class as the selector, yes you can:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Hj7/1/